# Greatest common divisor and smallest common multiple of N many numbers entered by user

Tags: c

I need to write a c program where N different positive numbers will be taken from the user to an integer A array with N elements. It will be assumed that the numbers will be entered as positive and it will not be checked if the numbers are not entered. The greatest common divisor and the smallest common multiple of all these integers will be calculated and written on the screen.
Example: For N = 4, the values received from the user should be stored in the A array as A = [10, 50, 15, 30]. As a result
The following output should be written on the screen.
GCD (10, 50, 15, 30) = 5, LCM (10, 50, 15,30) = 150

I can make compute the gcd and lcd of 2 numbers. **The problem is how i can do that for n many integer**. What kind of algorithm should i use? *Also another problem is that i can not define a function, i can't use break and continue commands.*

Here is my code for 2 integers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    
    printf("enter 2 integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);

    while(n1!=n2)
    {
        if(n1 > n2)
            n1 -= n2;
        else
            n2 -= n1;
    }
    printf("gcd = %d",n1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have for two numbers.

Comment: simple hint gcd(a, b, c) = gcd( gcd(a, b), c)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-two-array-numbers/

Comment: My approach to this question is dividing the numbers and then doing the process, as well. But how can i divide this kind of thing? N may be 5 or 3 or 10

Comment: Divide and conquer is a possibility. When given N numbers, you only have to be able to compute the gcd of (N+1)/2 numbers and then the gcd of both parts. Just iterate it until all parts have size 1 or 2.

Comment: How can i compute the gcd of (n+1)/2 numbers? I am a beginner and have no idea

Comment: Your task includes "N different positive numbers will be taken from the user **to an integer A array** with N elements" and "The following output should be written on the screen..." If you don't know how to calculate the GCD and LCM for N numbers you should at least implement the input and output part and calculate the GDC and LCM for the first two numbers. Then it is easier for us to help with the next steps. Where does the requirement come from that you cannot define a function? I consider this as bad programming style. I suggest to write a new question with modified code with a link to here

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the GCD of 2 positive integers, you can use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations). To calculate the LCM, simply note that `lcm(a,b) = a * b / gcd(a,b)`

Now, if you need to calculate the GCD and LCM of N numbers, realize that `gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(gcd(a,b), c)` and similarly, `lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(lcm(a,b),c)`. You should be able to develop an iterative algorithm to find the answer you want.

Below is my code to perform the task you described.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int lcm(int a, int b) {
  return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
}

int main(void) {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int g = 0, m = 1, x;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    g = gcd(g, x);
    m = lcm(m, x);
  }
  printf("gcd = %d\n", g);
  printf("lcm = %d\n", m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My approach to this question is the same with you. But problem is i can not define a function for my program

Comment: It's easy to change the above recursive GCD implementation to iterative, then you should be able to calculate it in main